# Why there is a restriction for a base-class subobject?

Tags: c++, types, base-class

3.9/2:

> For any object (**other than a base-class subobject**) of trivially
>   copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type
>   T, the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into
>   an array of char or unsigned char.

3.9/3:

> For any trivially copyable type T, if two pointers to T point to
>   distinct T objects obj1 and obj2, where **neither** obj1 **nor** obj2 is a
>   **base-class subobject**, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up obj1 are
>   copied into obj2, obj2 shall subsequently hold the same value as obj1.

I understand these rules formally, but I'm interested what is the point of such restrictions?

Comment: Probably because of the empty base optimization.

Comment: @T.C. It's not quite clear. Could you provide an example to explain?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Given `struct T {}; struct D : T { int x; };`, `sizeof(T) == 1`, but in `D` the base class subobject may have zero size.

Comment: I believe TC has a point, I didn't know of EBO but sounds definitely the reason for avoiding base class subobjects

Comment: @T.C. I know what empty base class optimization is. I meant I would like to look at an example which can cause a problem.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv That *is* an example where it would cause a problem. Using `memcpy` to copy the `T` subobject to another `D` object would overwrite one byte of `x`.

Comment: @hvd Indeed. I just didn't understand what T.C. means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Base class subobjects may have padding at the end that gets used by a derived class. Given two classes,

```
struct A {
  int a;
  char b;
};
struct B : A {
  char c;
};
```

it's entirely possible that `sizeof(A) == sizeof(B)`. If they are equal, it should be clear that things break if you simply use `memcpy` to copy the `A` subobject: you wouldn't be able to prevent reading or even overwriting the `c` value.

Your implementation may or may not re-use padding like that. A valid reason for designing an ABI where the padding is *not* re-used is precisely to deal nicely with code that does, incorrectly, use `memcpy` for such subobjects.

The comments give an example with empty base classes. That's one particular case where current implementations are very likely to re-use a byte of the base class, but it's not the only time it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of value-screwing due to base class subobjects and [EBO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {}; // empty class

struct Derived1 : Base {
public:    
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    // the size of any object of empty class type is at least 1
    assert(sizeof(Base) == 1);

    // empty base optimization applies
    assert(sizeof(Derived1) == sizeof(int));

    Base objBase;
    Derived1 objDerived;
    objDerived.i = 42;
    Base& refToobjDerived = objDerived;

    char buf[sizeof(Base)]; // 1

    std::memcpy(buf, &objBase, sizeof(Base)); // copy objBase to buf
    // might do something with buf..
    std::memcpy(&refToobjDerived, buf, sizeof(Base)); // EBO! I'm overwriting the int's value!

    std::cout << objDerived.i; // Screwed
}
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f94c3e063eac85d)

If you render the base class [non-trivially-copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable), the value will not be touched.

Another problem as hvd highlighted could lie in additional padding at the end of the base class that gets used to store derived-owned data.